# How are windows DLL actually shared?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management, dll, shared-memory

By examing several DLLs I have in my windows machine (for instance KERNEL32.DLL) I've notice that none of their sections, not even the read only data section have the IMAGE_SCN_MEM_SHARED flag set.

DLLs are mapped from the .dll file so only when you read a page of the file it is copied to physical memory but still, if the same page of let's say kernel32.dll is accessed by both process A and process B then the page will exist twice in physical memory. **I am asking for the veracity of this last statement.**

If the .text or the .rodata segment where shared they would get copied to physical memory only onced, even when ASLR is enabled because what ASLR does is randomize the base of a module when it is first loaded (with corresponding relocations applied) but the next process that loads this module untill system restart will get the module at the same address so the .text and .rodata could be shared in the same manner.

These are all assumptions I made, please correct me.

Thanks!

Comment: I think ASLR kind of disables the sharing. But good question!

Comment: ASLR randomises virtual addresses. The same physical address can be mapped to multiple virtual addresses, and can be different for each process.

Comment: @PaulStelian I think ASLR wouldn't break shareability as long as all process who load the DLL load it at the same address, which as far as I know it's true. After the system restarts the dlls would get different base addresses that what they had in the previous session, but a particular dll would be be loaded at the same (randomized at startup) address for all the processes that use it.

Comment: @Jonathan The DLLs are (probably) not position independent code, so loading code made for one address in another will break it.

Comment: I don't understand, why would an OS make two copies of dll code in memory?  I believe it would be more advantageous to load the dll into memory, then keep track of which DLLs are in memory and their locations.

Comment: A possibility is that an OS will load code into memory *for each process* to keep the processes isolated.  This helps prevent any re-rentrancy issues.

Comment: all this covered in Jeffrey Richter  "Windows® via C/C++" - `chapter 17 - Memory-Mapped Executables and DLLs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS will definitely be able to map multiple virtual addresses to the same physical memory page, as long as the page content does not (need to) change [in different ways for different processes]. However, if the code uses an absolute address (either internally or externally to the DLL), for example a vtable/function pointers, pointers to global data (constant or non-constant) or simply function calls with absolute addresses, the address must be modified to match the actual address given by the OS to that section of memory. This is called "relocation".

So, at least in theory, you can share the same DLL even with address space randomization, it just requires a little more work from the compiler and/or programmer. In particular, it requires that there are no relocations (in large chunks of the code). If the code has absolute addresses that are relocated based on the code-address, then it will need to have one copy per DLL.

I don't actually *know* how the OS deals with this. A simple solution is obviously to randomize the address only once per DLL (until that particular DLL is unloaded), regardless of how many applications use the same DLL. It still makes it rather hard for an outsider to know what address the DLL is loaded at, since it will load at a different address each time it gets loaded the first time (and more importantly, it will not be a static value for ALL machines using the same version of OS, which would be the case without this feature). It does, however, mean that long-running processes can be "inspected" by copying content from for example the stack that has known content. Web servers, database servers and system services are typically long-running processes, and as such will have different addresses only when the system is "shut down" (or at least the long running process is restarted).

The second, slightly trickier version is to check if a particular page (typically 4KB region of memory) has relocations, and share all the pages that have no relocation. Relocated pages need to have one copy per base address. It is typical to have "all references to external resources" in one block in DLL's (a "thunk section"), so the typical big part of a DLL wouldn't regardless of what the base address of the code, which means that is definitely a workable solution.

If neither of these schemes "work" in the OS, then you have to load the same DLL multiple times. This clearly works from the perspective of the OS anyway, as prior to ASLR, the base-address of the same DLL will need to be moved in case of two DLL's trying to load at the same address (for example DLL's produced by different vendors, that happen to pick the same base-address for the code, or the classic and common "I never gave a base address, so it uses the default address") - the OS will resolve such conflicts by changing the base address of the one loaded first.

As to the meaning of `IMAGE_SCN_MEM_SHARED`, I would have thought that the developer would request this, where the sharing of pages in a DLL is done automatically. In other words `IMAGE_SCN_MEM_SHARED` will be set by the developer of a particular DLL or EXE to signify the content *should* be shared with other users of the same content, rather than "the OS can share it if it can be done without the user of the content noticing" (which is certainly the case for sharing code, and (writeable) data is typically not shared between DLL's. Read-only data, as long as it has no relocations, can of course implicitly be shared [the user of that content can not tell if it is shared or not].

Comment: I think the last paragraph of your answer totally nailed it for me. I've been skimming through Windoes via C/C++ and confirmed it. The problem was that I misunderstood the menaing of `IMAGE_SCN_MEM_SHARED`. What actually happens (maybe I'm wrong again) is that the same physical pages are used for the section of the dlls as long as there is no write operation on a page. So normally most parts of the dll are loaded only once in physical memory. When a thread in a process writes to a section of the dll that page is copied to a new blank page commited in the page file.

Comment: I think this is called copy-on-write and it's a memory protection flag. `IMAGE_SCN_MEM_SHARED` effectively disables this flag on the pages of the sections it is applied to, so the changes that one thread does to these pages will be visible to other threads in other processes that use the dll.

Comment: Yes, copy-on-write is a popular (and relatively simple) solution as to how to solve all of the above problems of "checking for relocations" or "writing different global data depending on address" or whatever [if the OS is really clever, it can also check if the write is for the same value as there already is]. I don't have a windows machine, so I can't actually say what happens, but my linux machine definitely does have a different address for the same DLL function on two different processes using the DLL.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score -1):

Windows mostly uses explicit linking for most of Win DLLs , which is also called dynamic loading or run-time linking. The executable explicitly calls one of the functions LoadLibrary() OR LoadLibraryEx() API with the name of the required DLL. Calls to functions inside the loaded DLL need to be made via a function pointer.

In the implicit Linking, Windows does the DLL loading based on the contents of the executable. In the explicit case, the executable does the loading. e.g. Most files are shared in below path:
'C:\Windows\System32' as Shared Path & files such as 'kernel32.dll', 'user32.dll', etc.

Comment: *"Windows mostly uses explicit linking for most of Win DLLs"* - Citation needed. Beyond that, this doesn't even attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Can we take reference from below link.?   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#:~:text=Each%20section%20has%20its%20own,space%20in%20the%20page%20file.

Comment: I fail to find evidence in that random web link to support the statement that *"Windows mostly uses explicit linking for most of Win DLLs"*.